# Using SQL to find the "Active" Daily Average in a Range of Months

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that contains the following columns:

```
ID       |  START_DATE   |  END_DATE
1001     |  02/02/2023   |  03/05/2023
1001     |  03/07/2023   |  11/05/2023
1002     |  03/05/2023   |  10/20/2023
1003     |  03/07/2023   |  04/07/2023
1004     |  04/07/2023   |  04/17/2023
1005     |  04/18/2023   |  05/19/2023
1006     |  05/19/2023   |  06/14/2023
1007     |  05/24/2023   |  06/28/2023
1008     |  10/31/2022   |  12/01/2022
1008     |  12/03/2022   |  10/07/2023
1009     |  12/01/2022   |  03/22/2023
1010     |  04/03/2023   |  05/04/2023
1011     |  05/04/2023   |  05/23/2023
1012     |  05/23/2023   |  10/02/2023
1013     |  06/15/2023   |  07/21/2023
1014     |  01/27/2023   |  02/07/2023
1015     |  05/02/2023   |  05/18/2023
1016     |  05/18/2023   |  06/18/2023
1017     |  06/18/2023   |  07/27/2023
1018     |  05/01/2023   |  09/30/2023
1019     |  11/22/2022   |  02/22/2023
1020     |  02/02/2022   |  05/04/2023
```

For a twelve month period (which could include any 12 month period), I need a summary of all the daily averages for each month.

Final product would look something like:

```
Month   Daily Ave.
Oct-22   37.6
Nov-22   37.9 
Dec-22   24.1 
Jan-23   26.5 
Feb-23   24.0 
Mar-23   35.8 
Apr-23   35.2 
May-23   31.8 
Jun-23   26.5 
Jul-23   20.1 
Aug-23   23.0 
Sep-23   33.2
```

This table contains IDs that were "active" between two dates.

This table also contains duplicate IDs due to an ID being "active" during more than one time period.

There should only be one unique ID that is "active" for any given day, but I guess there could be bad data to account for that has overlapping "active" days.  If so, only IDs should only be counted once per day at most.

To determine a monthly daily average, first take the daily count for all "active" IDs on each day of the month, then add these daily counts together, and divide by the number of days in that month.

This need to be repeated for each of the 12 months in the range.

If you were to manually calculate this, it would be something like...

1. Check for all IDs that have a date range that matches the date of 10/1/2022, then record that count.
2. Repeat above step for all days of this month: 10/2, 10/3, 10/4, etc.
3. Sum all of the totals for each day of the steps above and divide by the # days in the month.
4. Repeat each step above for each month in the range.

Other notes:

-The months are calendar months (e.g. 10/1/2022 to 10/31/2022)
-Month are never rolling months (such as 11/10/2022 to 12/10/2022)
-The "active" start date of any ID may go back years and years, so you cannot make a correlation of start date to the month you are using in the reportable range requested.

What might be a solution via SQL, particularly the DB2 flavor of SQL?

I have created a convoluted method via exporting via SQL to Excel and creating arrays of formulas for each day and month and all IDs, whether dupes or not, that pulls that data and does a simple zero or 1 count.  This is repeated in a similar fashion in another tab for just a list of unique IDs to account for the duplicate listing of IDs that have multiple "active" date ranges.  This is cumbersome and human error prone.

Comment: You should include all the possible edge cases into your sample data - in particular "duplicates" &/or "overlaps" and then provide an "expected result" based on that sample data. This helps clarify what you actually intend as words are open to wide, & sometimes wild, interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table of dates, or as below a CTE to generate a wanted range of dates, then join your data to that. This will allow you to spread ids from the start to end dates, then using count(distinct ...) duplications are removed from the final result.

```
WITH dates (dt) AS (
    SELECT DATE('2022-02-01') AS dt
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + 1 DAYS
    FROM dates
    WHERE dt < '2023-09-30'
)
SELECT 
    YEAR(d.dt) AS year
  , MONTH(d.dt) AS month
  , COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID) cd_tid
  , COUNT(DISTINCT d.dt) cd_ddt
  , (COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID) * 1.0) / (COUNT(DISTINCT d.dt) * 1.0) AS Daily_Ave
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN ActiveIDs t ON d.dt BETWEEN t.START_DATE AND t.END_DATE
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(d.dt)
  , MONTH(d.dt)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(d.dt)
  , MONTH(d.dt)
```

| YEAR | MONTH | CD_TID | CD_DDT | DAILY_AVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 2 | 1 | 28 | 0.035714285714285714 |
| 2022 | 3 | 1 | 31 | 0.032258064516129032 |
| 2022 | 4 | 1 | 30 | 0.033333333333333333 |
| 2022 | 5 | 1 | 31 | 0.032258064516129032 |
| 2022 | 6 | 1 | 30 | 0.033333333333333333 |
| 2022 | 7 | 1 | 31 | 0.032258064516129032 |
| 2022 | 8 | 1 | 31 | 0.032258064516129032 |
| 2022 | 9 | 1 | 30 | 0.033333333333333333 |
| 2022 | 10 | 2 | 31 | 0.064516129032258064 |
| 2022 | 11 | 3 | 30 | 0.100000000000000000 |
| 2022 | 12 | 4 | 31 | 0.129032258064516129 |
| 2023 | 1 | 5 | 31 | 0.161290322580645161 |
| 2023 | 2 | 6 | 28 | 0.214285714285714285 |
| 2023 | 3 | 6 | 31 | 0.193548387096774193 |
| 2023 | 4 | 8 | 30 | 0.266666666666666666 |
| 2023 | 5 | 13 | 31 | 0.419354838709677419 |
| 2023 | 6 | 10 | 30 | 0.333333333333333333 |
| 2023 | 7 | 7 | 31 | 0.225806451612903225 |
| 2023 | 8 | 5 | 31 | 0.161290322580645161 |
| 2023 | 9 | 5 | 30 | 0.166666666666666666 |

nb: you could create a calendar table instead of using a recursive CTE each time, this would also benefit by being indexed.

Also see working query at https://dbfiddle.uk/WoLWqDxW